# Error importing javascript class

Tags: javascript, wavesurfer.js

**Update**

I replaced

`import {WaveSurfer} from "js/wavesurfer.js/src/wavesurfer.js"`

by

`import WaveSurfer from "./js/wavesurfer.js/src/wavesurfer.js"`

and it now seems to be imported, but I now get the following error:

`SyntaxError: bad method definition (wavesurfer.js:179:4)` (see corresponding line [here](https://github.com/katspaugh/wavesurfer.js/blob/master/src/wavesurfer.js#L179))

---

I am trying to run an example from [wavesurfer.js](https://github.com/katspaugh/wavesurfer.js) with a local clone of the code.

With the code shown below, I get

```
SyntaxError: import declarations may only appear at top level of a module (wavesurfer.js:1)
```

Following the advice given [here](https://jakearchibald.com/2017/es-modules-in-browsers/), I replace the first line in `index.html` by

```
<script type='module'>
import {WaveSurfer} from "js/wavesurfer.js/src/wavesurfer.js"
</script>
```

and got

```
ReferenceError: WaveSurfer is not defined (zoom.js:1:5)
TypeError: Error resolving module specifier: js/wavesurfer.js src/wavesurfer.js index.html:4:25
```

How am I supposed to import `WaveSurfer`?

**index.html**

```
<script src="js/wavesurfer.js/src/wavesurfer.js"></script>
<script src="js/zoom.js"></script>

<div id="waveform"></div>

...
```

**zoom.js**

```
var wavesurfer = WaveSurfer.create({
  container: '#waveform',
  waveColor: 'red',
  progressColor: 'purple'
});

wavesurfer.load('https://ia902606.us.archive.org/35/items/shortpoetry_047_librivox/song_cjrg_teasdale_64kb.mp3');

...
```

Answer (score 0):

Hoping this to work. try relative path.

```
<script type='module'>
import { WaveSurfer } from "./src/wavesurfer.js"
</script>
```

Comment: The path is correct, but I had to add `./` before. See my update.

Comment: My local version of `wavesurfer.js` is at `./js/wavesurfer.js/src/wavesurfer.js` (relatively to my `index.html`, not `./src/wavesurfer.js`...